# Response design and two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, responsive-design

Hi I got one activity and 3 fragments.
1st fragment - List of items ---click---> it has to open layout and inflate there two frameLayouts with fragment 2 and fragment 3.

Here is the code in fragment 1 onItemClickListener

```
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_frame_list_600_detailed, detailedFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                StepDescriptionFragment stepDescriptionFragment =
                        StepDescriptionFragment.getInstance(itemClicked.getSteps(), 0);

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_frame_list_600_step, stepDescriptionFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Here is the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablet_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_frame_list_600_detailed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_frame_list_600_step"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the error.

```
 07-09 14:34:14.547 9066-9066/com.example.boris.bakingapp E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f080072 (com.example.boris.bakingapp:id/main_frame_list_600_detailed) for fragment DetailedFragment{9ee18e2 #1 id=0x7f080072}
    Activity state:
    07-09 14:34:14.596 9066-9066/com.example.boris.bakingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.boris.bakingapp, PID: 9066
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080072 (com.example.boris.bakingapp:id/main_frame_list_600_detailed) for fragment DetailedFragment{9ee18e2 #1 id=0x7f080072}
```

So it suppose to put fragments in that views but it doesn't see it

Comment: Did you reference the correct layout and does it exist? According to your log `main_frame_list_600_detailed` can't be found.

Comment: @HB. yes. thats why im confused. Everything looks correct https://github.com/borisruzanov/BakingApp/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout-sw600dp/fragment_detailed_step.xml

Comment: You can place a fragments in a `FrameLayout`, but you are trying to replace a fragment with a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @HB.  i have tried add method either. the same error

Comment: Create a different layout, place the content that is in `main_frame_list_600_detailed` inside that layout, then inflate the layout and not the framelayout.

Comment: It's simple, you are trying to inflate a fragment that is not a fragment, but a framelayout.  FragmentManager expects a fragment, not a framelayout.

Comment: @HB. the problem is that it is only one framelayout in main activity and after click it has to be two framelayouts. So I see only one solution to make extra activity for extra layout with two frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it says no view found for "detailedFragment" please define it as you have done for "stepDescriptionFragment "

please show some more code like you have shown this :

```
StepDescriptionFragment stepDescriptionFragment =
                    StepDescriptionFragment.getInstance(itemClicked.getSteps(), 0);
```

Comment: thank you for help. But what code you need? The rest code is code for fragment where the user is

Comment: i mean where you have defined "detailedFragment" just like you did for "stepDescriptionFragment"

Comment: DetailedFragment detailedFragment = new DetailedFragment();
                detailedFragment.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: you are using a framelayout in your xml.
change them to fragment.

Comment: only a fragment can replace a fragment

Comment: when you excute => fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_frame_list_600_detailed, detailedFragment)
 
what it does is search for a fragment "detailedFragment" with id="main_frame_list_600_detailed" and returns with IllegalArgumentException